# Can copy hdfs file from hadoop cluster KERBEROS to other Cluster NOT KERBEROS?

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, hortonworks-data-platform

I did have one Hadoop cluster with KERBEROS security and other Hadoop Cluster withous KERBEROS.

Can I copy file from KERBEROS hadoop cluster to NON KERBEROS Hadoop Cluster?

Comment: Yes, `distcp` has an option that disables strict security checks. It's just a matter of finding the exact syntax...

Answer (score 1):

one option [set up in core-site.xml](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_administration/content/distcp_and_security_settings.html):
add property

```
<property>
 <name>ipc.client.fallback-to-simple-auth-allowed</name>
 <value>true</value>
</property>
```

other option [add parameter in command](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/294/running-distcp-between-two-cluster-one-kerberized.html):

for example

```
hadoop distcp -D ipc.client.fallback-to-simple-auth-allowed=true hdfs://nn1:8020/foo/bar hdfs://nn2:8020/bar/foo
```

Comment: This is also covered in https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-12-x/topics/cdh_admin_distcp_secure_insecure.html.